# extract multidimentional array into a nested list

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I'm trying to extract a multidimensional array I got from a [Nestable Plugin](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) into a `Ordered List` by the Plugin's `HTML` structure.

The Recursion I've build is not enought because the `OL` tag I'm creating is out side the `LI` that got children. At first glance it looked like an easy task, but I've failed to complete it.

**This is what I've wrote so far**, I cant understand how do I check if the next loop in the recursion is the `LI` that have children, so the `OL` will be inside, with the buttons and the handle `div`. 
(example of the plugin's HTML structure can be seen below)

```
function buildNestedList($a) {

    if (!is_array($a)) {
        echo ('<li class="dd-item" data-name="'.$a.'"><div class="dd-handle">'.$a.'</div></li>');
        return;
    }

    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if(($k=="children")&&(is_string($k))) {
            echo ('<ol class="dd-list">');
        buildNestedList($v);
            echo ("</ol></li>");
        }
        else {
            printAll($v);
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the output of my function:**

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
   <ol class="dd-list">
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 1">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 2">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 2</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 3">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 3</div>
      </li>
      <ol class="dd-list">
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 4">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 4</div>
         </li>
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 5">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 5</div>
         </li>
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 6">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 6</div>
         </li>
         <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 7">
               <div class="dd-handle">item 7</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 8">
               <div class="dd-handle">item 8</div>
            </li>
         </ol>
      </ol>
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 9">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 9</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 10">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 10</div>
      </li>
      <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 11">
         <div class="dd-handle">item 11</div>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

**This is the a example of an `Array` I've got from DB:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 3
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => item 4
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => item 5
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => item 6
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => item 7
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => item 8
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => item 11
        )

)
```

**This is the correct plugin's `HTML` structure example:**

```
<ol class="dd-list">
   <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 1">
      <div class="dd-handle">item 1</div>
   </li>
   <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 2">
      <button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
      <div class="dd-handle">item 2</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 3">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 3</div>
         </li>
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 4">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 4</div>
         </li>
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 5">
            <div class="dd-handle">item 5</div>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
   <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 6">
      <button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
      <div class="dd-handle">item 6</div>
      <ol class="dd-list">
         <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 7">
            <button data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button><button data-action="expand" type="button" style="display: none;">Expand</button>
            <div class="dd-handle">item 7</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
               <li class="dd-item" data-name="item 8">
                  <div class="dd-handle">item 8</div>
               </li>
            </ol>
         </li>
      </ol>
   </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open and close tags properly.

Use this:

```
$source=json_decode('[{"name":"item 1"},{"name":"item 2"},{"name":"item 3","children":[{"name":"item 4"},{"name":"item 5"},{"name":"item 6","children":[{"name":"item 7"},{"name":"item 8"}]}]},{"name":"item 9"},{"name":"item 10"},{"name":"item 11"}]',true);

function buildNestedList(array $a)
{
    if(empty($a["name"]))
    {
        echo "<ol>";
        foreach($a as $item)
        {
            buildNestedList($item);
        }
        echo "</ol>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<li><div>".$a["name"]."</div>";
        if(!empty($a["children"]))
        {
            buildNestedList($a["children"]);
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
buildNestedList($source);
```

[PHP Live demo](http://3v4l.org/trFpp)

Please be noted that I pretty-print a little bit on the live demo above.

Here is the simple sample of the generated nested list: http://jsfiddle.net/YDnd8/